# How does CSS media queries based on pixels work with modern smart phones?

Tags: css, media-queries

Consider a smart phone with screen resolution 1440 x 2960 pixels. Now if I do a CSS mobile query like @media(max-width: 500px), then even though it is a mobile device it won't satisfy the media query.

But it does. Consider this website [Loruki](https://michaelfrieze-loruki.netlify.app/), it has the same media query of max-width of 500px, yet it works like a mobile based web page when opened from 1440 x 2960 device.

How does pixel and media query work?

Comment: You need to educate yourself on the difference between width and device-width (the latter being deprecated in the context of media queries).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing `screen resolution` with `screen width`

i.e. A phone's screen width is usually around 200 to 500 CSS pixels.

This famous blog post explains why there was the need for this being introduced: [a pixel is not a pixel](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html)

Medium also has [an excellent explanatory article on the topic](https://elad.medium.com/understanding-the-difference-between-css-resolution-and-device-resolution-28acae23da0b).

For high resolutions screens, the so-called device-to-pixel ratio is greater than 1. To calculate the CSS pixel width, this is the formula:

```
CSSPixelWidth = DevicePixelWidth / DevicePixelRatio
```

Comment: 200 to 500 what? pixels?

Comment: Yes, CSS pixels, which are not hardware pixels. They had to come up with this differentiation once hi res screens were out.